# Variable Setting to All Subclasses

Tags: java, reference

Is there a way to insantiate a variable that encompasses all subclasses of a class? From what I've read so far we must state what type the variable is before setting it equal to something:

Example:

ExampleObject1 object = **reference to the object**

But what if we wanted to make it so that we could set the variable to any instance or subclass of that object?

Comment: [Interfaces and Inheritance](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/index.html)

Comment: I'm not really clear from the question as posted, but is this a question about [static/class members](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html)?

Comment: Objects can't have subclasses or instances. Classes can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can already do that.

A variable of type `T` (as long as `T` is a class/interface/enum/annotation) can hold a reference to any instance of the class `T`, or any instance of a class that extends or implements `T`.

For example, this works:

```
class MyClass1 {
    // ... stuff goes here ...
}

class MyClass2 extends MyClass1 {
    // ... stuff goes here ...
}

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyClass1 object = new MyClass2();
    }
}
```